# perl command line substitute of strings

Tags: perl

perl has convenient command line syntax for substitution of files

```
perl -pe 's/key/replace/g' file
```

I am wondering what is the one liner syntax for substitution of string?

```
perl -pe 's/key/replace/g' string
```

doesn't work. It will complain

> Can't open ppp: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `echo` (or your operating system's equivalent) to send your string into your command-line Perl program.

```
$ echo hello | perl -pe 's/hello/goodbye/'
goodbye
```

Comment: But also using Here Strings: `perl -pe 's/key/replace/g' <<< 'string'`

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to remove the `-p` option as that is wrapping your code up inside a `while(<>)` loop. For perl `<>` means read in files specified on the command line or STDIN if there aren't any. So your "string" (which I'm guessing was "ppp" when you tried it) is being treated like a filename.

Instead if you want to pass in non-filenames you probably want something like:

```
perl -e 'print join(" ",map{ s/key/replace/g; $_ } @ARGV),"\n"' string
```

Comment: But keeping the `-p` and slightly abusing the `while` loop makes the code so much simpler :-)

Comment: @DaveCross true, but I thought it'd be useful to explain what the `-p` does and why the OP code would never work as is.